# How does self get bound in Python?

Tags: python, self

How does Python bind `self` when calling functions on an object? I'm trying to understand why this:

```py
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'class A'

    def show_name(self):
        print(self, self.name)

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.name = 'class B'
        self.show_name = a.show_name

A().show_name()
B(A()).show_name()
```

outputs

```py
(<self.A object at 0x7f9d35a06e50>, 'class A')
(<self.A object at 0x7f9d35a06e50>, 'class A')
```

**Edit**: How does it know that `show_name` should be given the instance of class `A` as its first (`self`) parameter, not the instance of class `B`?

Comment: This is a dup of another question from just a couple months ago, but I can't find it. I _can_ find [the blog post](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-methods-work.html) I wrote to help explain the answer.

Comment: @abarnert Great article. I had no idea you could just add a `__call__` method to any type and have it be callable.

Comment: @Jeremy: I was assuming you're using Python 3.x here because you're calling `print` as a function… but looking at the output, that looks like Python 2.x. Do you want me to edit my answer to explain how 2.x works? (It's a bit more complicated, and the names of the special attributes are different, but the basic idea is the same.)

Comment: @abarnert I understand it now enough for my purposes, Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the full details, see [this blog post](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-methods-work.html). But I can summarize here.

The key is to understand bound methods. A bound method is just an object that holds the actual function object, and the instance it's bound to. Something like this:

```
class BoundMethod(object):
    def __init__(self, function, instance):
        self.__func__ = function
        self.__self__ = instance
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.__func__(self.__self__, *args, **kwargs)
```

Bound methods are first-class objects, so you can pass them around and inspect them:

```
>>> class C:
...     def foo(self):
...         print(self)
>>> C.foo
<function __main__.foo>
>>> c = C()
>>> c.foo
<bound method C.foo of <__main__.C object at 0x10ab90a90>>
>>> c.foo.__func__
<function __main__.foo>
>>> c.foo.__func__ is C.foo, c.foo.__self__ is c
(True, True)
```

And you can even construct them manually:

```
>>> import types
>>> f = types.MethodType(C.foo, 2)
>>> f
<bound method int.foo of 2>
>>> f()
2
```

(While my Python class above obviously isn't the real code, it's not far off; you'll even get most of the same errors if you do silly things like try to bind a bound method or a non-callable.)

---

So, how does `c.foo` end up bound to `c`? To really understand that, you need to understand descriptors. But the short version is this:

Almost every type in Python has an extra method `__get__`. And this is used for attribute access. Basically, when you type `c.foo`, it does something like this (ignoring base classes, slots, getattr overrides, etc.):

```
try:
    return c.__dict__['foo']
except KeyError:
    value = type(c).__dict__['foo']
    try:
        return value.__get__(c)
    except AttributeError:
        return value
```

The `__get__` method on a function object returns a bound method (bound to its argument).

---

So, going back to your example, obviously `B(A()).show_name()` prints out stuff about `A` because `B(A()).show_name` is bound to an `A` instance… but how does that happen?

Well, let's trace through this:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> b = B(a)
>>> b.show_name
```

Inside your `__init__` function, you do this:

```
self.show_name = a.show_name
```

That's just copying the already-bound method `a.show_name` to a normal instance variable `self.show_name`. So, when you later look up `b.show_name`, it's the same bound method, bound to `a`. If you want to re-bind it, you'll have to do it manually, something like:

```
self.show_name = types.MethodType(a.show_name.__func__, self)
```

Comment: Ok so if I'm understanding correctly, if you just skip adding assigning anything to the `show_name` attribute of the `B` instance in the constructor entirely, wouldn't you get the same result as assigning `types.MethodType(...`? That is, the interpreter, not finding `show_name` on the `B` instance or on `B`, would go up the lookup chain until it eventually found it on class `A`. It would find a property descriptor that returns a bound method, and retrieve the method bound to the `B` instance that this descriptor would return. Is that correct?

Comment: @Asad: If `B` were a subclass of `A`, yes. But both the OP and my answer defined them as independent classes, both inheriting only from `object`, so `A` won't be on the lookup chain. (You can see the lookup chain as `B.__mro__`, and you can learn how it works [here](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/).)

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. I hadn't read the question carefully and was assuming B inherited from A for some reason.

Comment: @Asad: Also, it's a bit confusing to say "property descriptor", because that term usually specifically refers to the descriptors used to implement the `@property` decorator. Just "descriptor" or "attribute descriptor" for the more general case (or "non-data descriptor" or "non-data function descriptor" for the specific case of a typical method).

Comment: I see. Coming from C#, I tend to think of descriptors as equivalents to getter-setter-pair properties (except that descriptors exist independently as objects). That may have gotten mixed up into my terminology.

Answer (score 4):

It's bound when you do `a.show_name` in `B`'s constructor. Thus, when you fetch `show_name` from an instance of `B`, it's already bound to `a`, so it doesn't bind to the instance of `B`.

Comment: Could you expand on how that binding in `B`'s constructor works?

Comment: It's not specific to it being in `B`'s constructor. Any time you fetch an unbound method on an instance as is the case with `a.show_name` you get an method bound to that instance.

Comment: This is a great concise explanation, covering 90% of what you need to know in only two lines.